# Looking for a book about a drug that causes habitual users to cross to another world that has an extra color

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I've been trying to find a book that I read in the early 90's, but that judging from the cover was published in the late 60's/early 70's about a drug epidemic that was actually backed by the UN because of overpopulation.  If you take enough of the drug you disappear, but end up in another world that has an extra color.

Comment: Sounds like Philip K. Dick...

Comment: I've looked through PKD bibliographies and it's not him as far as I can tell.  It was a bit more mystery and less out there than PKD.  More like a traditional mystery/private detective author got an idea on while on acid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [The Dreaming Earth](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/332039.The_Dreaming_Earth) by John Brunner!

It was published in 1963. This is the cover of my copy:

[image]

and here's another cover I've found online.

[image: [image]]

It's basically everything you've said:

The main character is a UN law enforcement agent in the Narcotics Deparement. It's set in the early 2000s, when the world's population has exploded and resources are extremely scarce. He's on the trail of a worldwide epidemic of a drug called "happy dreams" that no one can find the source of, which causes very intense dreaming/hallucinations. Habitual users end up vanishing--at first everyone assumes that they've simply left society, but it later turns out they're actually vanishing into another reality. The UN ends up being behind it; they describe it as "colonizing other worlds."

The extra color is called "varm," and is first experienced by the main character when he's injected with the drug, and later when he ends up crossing over. The description of the new world includes the phrase "the rainbow had eight colors."

Comment: That's it!  Thanks

Comment: It originally appeared n New Worlds as "Put Down This Earth".

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the book, but the blurb sounds a bit like Jeff Noon's [*Vurt*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312141440), published in 1993. The cover and subject look a little 60s-70s-ish.

blurb:

> Vurt is a feather—a drug, a dimension, a dream state, a virtual
>   reality. It comes in many colors: legal Blues for lullaby dreams.
>   Blacks, filled with tenderness and pain, just beyond the law. Pink
>   Pornovurts, doorways to bliss. Silver feathers for techies who know
>   how to remix colors and open new dimensions. And Yellows—the feathers
>   from which there is no escape.
>  The beautiful young Desdemona is
>   trapped in Curious Yellow, the ultimate Metavurt, a feather few have
>   ever seen and fewer still have dared ingest. Her brother Scribble will
>   risk everything to rescue his beloved sister. Helped by his gang, the
>   Stash Riders, hindered by shadowcops, robos, rock and roll dogmen, and
>   his own dread, Scribble searches along the edges of civilization for a
>   feather that, if it exists at all, must be bought with the one thing
>   no sane person would willingly give.

Comment: I _have_ read the book, and while it contains the concept of different coloured drugs, I don't recall the feathers being UN backed, nor another world having an extra colour. But it's a good excuse to reread and check to be certain.

Comment: Not Vurt, there's a single drug and users eventually disappear with I believe their clothes left behind.  I know I read it between 1990-1992, it had a psychedelic cover and was falling apart from the glue being too old, so guessing on the publish date.

Answer (score 0):

I read this book and have been looking again. The title I read it under in 1979 was “Happy Dreams”. I just told the story to my wife last night, because of what I see going on. I’m still looking...

Comment: Hi, we expect longer answers than this, explaining why the suggested work answers the question. If you could add some more details, it would improve your chances of the answer being accepted.

Comment: Check powell's - that's where I often find older books, or abebooks. Took a bit for the Dreaming Earth to come in but I got an alert when it did